# How can I change TextAlign to Center in the ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, text-alignment

Has anyone got any idea in how can I change `TextAlign` to `Center` in the `ListView`? As it is shown in the photo, when I select `Center` from the list it goes back to `Left` so I cant select `Left` option.
is there a way of doing that? I just want to place the cell text to the center instead of left.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Go to your Listview properties and check out the "collection" property when you modify it this shows up

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think it would help if you could provide *a complete list of steps to reproduce the issue* (e.g. (1) create a new C# WinForms Framework 3.5 project in Visual Studio 2015, (2) create a new Form, (3) ...), so that people can test if it happens on their system as well.

Comment: a trick would be to add empty column (no text. length would be `n/3` where n is total width of listview) at left. then add second column after that which will become center

Answer (score 4):

You have problem just for *first column* and you haven't problem with *other columns*. From [`MSDN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.textalign(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Due to a limitation in the underlying control, this property has no effect on the first column in the ListView control, which is always aligned to the left. To work around this limitation in .NET Framework version 2.0, you can handle the [`ListView.DrawColumnHeader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawcolumnheader(v=vs.100).aspx) event and paint the column header yourself.